# jQuery show/hide a div based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list with values 'all' and 'custom'. On select with value 'custom' a div with class 'resources' should appear, and if the value is 'all' it should be hidden.

Form is:

```
<div>
    <label>Privileges:</label>
    <select name="privileges" id="privileges" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
        <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
        <option id="custom" value="custom">Custom</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="resources" style=" display: none;">resources</div>
```

And javascript for this is:

```
ShowPrivileges: function() {
    var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges');
    var select = this.value;
    Privileges.change(function() {
        if (select === 'custom') {
            $('.resources').show();
        }
    });
}
```

How should this look in order to work? Sorry, I know this should be simple, but I am new with all this.

Comment: is craateUserJsObject... spelled properly? Or is it supposed to be createUserJsObject ?

Comment: Thank you all. Response of @dfsq worked perfectly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use val method:

```
var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'custom') {
        $('.resources').show();
    }
    else $('.resources').hide(); // hide div if value is not "custom"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RWUdb/

Comment: Why do you need the second line? That variable is never used

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up the HTML by dropping the onClick and removing the IDs from the options.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Privileges:</label>
    <select name="privileges" id="privileges">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="resources" style=" display: none;">resources</div>
```

And your JavaScript could simply do this:

```
$('#privileges').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).val() === 'all') {
            $('.resources').hide();
        } else {
            $('.resources').show();
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Privileges.on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='custom'){
        $('.resources').show();
    }else{
        $('.resources').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, this works to show but it doesnt hide the div if the value 'all' is selected

Comment: if($(this).val()=='custom'){
    $('.resources').show();
}else{
    $('.resources').hide();
}

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the event handler:

```
$("#privileges").change(craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges);
```

Then, within your ShowPrivileges funciton:

```
var val = $("#privileges").val();
if(val == "whatever")
    //do something
else
    //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#privileges").change(function(){
     var select=  $(this).val();
       if(select=='custom'){
          //some code
         }
    });
```

**or**

```
  var select=$('#privileges :selected').val()
    if(select=='custom'){
    //some code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this too complicated:

First off, drop the inline `onclick`. Since you are using jQuery, attach your handler dynamically.

```
<div>
    <label>Privileges:</label>
    <select name="privileges" id="privileges">
        <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
        <option id="custom" value="custom">Custom</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="resources" style=" display: none;">resources</div>
```

Secondly, don't listen for the click and then attach the `change` handler.  Attach it directly

```
<script>
jQuery('#privileges').on('change',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val()=='custom'){
        jQuery('.resources').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('.resources').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### That could be done with `toggle()` as a shorthand :

```
$('#privileges').change(function() {
  $('.resources').toggle($(this).val() == 'custom');
});
```

If you want to **toggle the display in the page load** you could trigger the same `change()` event, like :

```
$('#privileges').change(function() {
  $('.resources').toggle($(this).val() == 'custom');
}).change();
```

```js
$('#privileges').change(function() {
  $('.resources').toggle($(this).val() == 'custom');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Privileges:</label>
  <select name="privileges" id="privileges">
    <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
    <option id="custom" value="custom">Custom</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="resources" style=" display: none;">resources</div>
```