# Hide div when listbox value changes

Tags: javascript, css, html, listbox

OK I have 4 div's and I want to show them when the value of the listbox is the same as the div id
sorry guys this is probably an eazsy question but I am new to JavaScript
This is for a recurring events page for a calendar entry.

for example

```
<select name="Repeat" id="Repeat">
    <option value="Never">Never</option>
    <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
    <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
  </select>

<div id="Daily" if selected in listbox "repeat" make this div visible else hide>
daily events
</div>

<div id="Weekly" if selected in listbox "repeat" make this div visible else hide>
weekly events
</div>

<div id="Monthly" if selected in listbox "repeat" make this div visible else hide>
monthly events
</div>

<div id="Yearly" if selected in listbox "repeat" make this div visible else hide>
yearly events
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery show hide div based on select value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645652/jquery-show-hide-div-based-on-select-value) - This answer involves jQuery, but it shouldn't be too hard to translate into pure Javascript.

Comment: I'am not really sure why i created this- but if you've had used radio-buttons or checkboxes you could have done it with CSS alone.  http://jsfiddle.net/6UAhk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to use plain javascript:
1. add onchange to the select

```
<select name="Repeat" id="Repeat" onchange="changeRepeat(this.value)">
```

and the function should go like this:

```
function changeRepeat(value){
  if(value == "Never"){
    document.getElementById('Daily').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Weekly').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Monthly').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Yearly').style.display = "none";
    //document.getElementById('Yearly').style.display = "block"; to show
  }
  //else if value == daily, weekly...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery quite easily. Just use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#Repeat").change(function(){

        $("div").fadeOut();
        $("#"+$(this).val()).fadeIn();

    });

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T37y5/)

---

If you **need** to do this with pure Javascript, you can do with the [`onChange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event:

**HTML:**

```
<select ... onchange="hideShow()">
```

**JS:**

```
function hideShow()
{
    document.getElementById("Daily").style.display = "none";   
    document.getElementById("Weekly").style.display = "none";   
    document.getElementById("Monthly").style.display = "none";   
    document.getElementById("Yearly").style.display = "none";   

    document.getElementById(document.getElementById("Repeat").value).style.display = "block";   
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T37y5/3/)