# Changing two input values to one

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the two input boxes from feet/inches to one input box to centimeters when centimeters is selected as an option. It works with feet and inches but I want only one input when user selects centimeters. How would I able to change it using javascript?

```
 <form action=" " onsubmit="">Enter your Height:
  <input type="text" id="height"> </input> 
  Feet <input type="text" id="height2"> </input>Inches
    <select id = "typeH">
        <option value = "feet">Feet/Inches</option>
        <option value = "cm">Centimeter</option>
    </select>
```

Here is one of the function in my js code:

```
function calculateBMI() {
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  var height2 = document.getElementById('height2').value;
  var typeW = document.getElementById("type").value;
  var typeH = document.getElementById("typeH").value;
  if (typeW === "lbs") {
    weight = weight * 0.45;
  } else if (typeW === "kg") {
    weight = weight;
  }
  if (typeH === "feet") {
    height = height * 0.3048;
    height2 = height2 * 0.0254;
    var totalheight = height + height2;
  } else if (typeH === "cm") { //this is the part where i want to change the two input boxes to one if the user selects cm as type of height
    typeH.addEventListner("click", change());
    //change();
    height = height * 0.0328084;
    height2 = 0;
    var totalheight = height + height2;
  }
  var total = weight / (totalheight * totalheight);
  roundToTwo(total);
  document.getElementById('result').value = roundToTwo(total);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post the javascript code that you have written so far to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Try an onclick event on the option-element (for centimeters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide elements based on a selected option with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832785/show-hide-elements-based-on-a-selected-option-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some javascript. Here is a quick and dirty solution, also using CSS:

```js
document.getElementById('typeH').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    // Mark all of them as hidden
    for(var i = 0; i < el.options.length; i++) {
      var spanEl = document.getElementById(el.options[i].value);
      spanEl.className = 'hidden';
      // Reset all of the input options
      var inputs = spanEl.querySelectorAll('input');
      for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
        inputs[j].value = '';
      }
    }
    // Show the one that was selected
    document.getElementById(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value).className = '';
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="">
  <span>Enter your Height:</span>
  <span id="feet"><!-- This id must match the value in the select option -->
    <input type="text" id="heightInFeet" name="heightInFeet"></input> Feet
    <input type="text" id="heightInInches" name="heightInInches"></input> Inches
  </span>
  <span id="cm" class="hidden">
    <input type="text" id="heightInCentimeters"></input> Centimeters
  </span>
  <select id="typeH">
    <option value="feet">Feet/Inches</option><!-- This value must match the id of the span -->
    <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

In the Javascript, we add an event listener to the `change` event of the `#typeH` select element. (This is the equivalent of putting a function in the `onChange` attribute inline in the HTML.)

In the CSS, we just add a class that hides the irrelevant elements.

In the HTML, we reorganize the DOM tree so the sections of inputs and text (namely for feet/inches and centimeters) into wrapper `span` elements. That way in javascript, we can hide all of the inputs in the spans, and then "show" (or rather, remove the `hidden` class) on the selected option.

Hopefully this is educational for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the code you are using to calculate the `weight` and `height` values, you need to use another code to handle the hiding/showing case.

You need to bind an `onchange` event on the `select` element where, you will hide/show the second `input` according to the selected value.

In your JS create the following function:

```
function filterHeight(select) {
  if (select.value !== "feet") {
    document.getElementById("height2").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("height2").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Where `document.getElementById("height2")` is used to refer the second input and `.style.display` is used to hide/show it.

Then in your HTML add `onchange="filterHeight(this)"` to the select element:

```
<select id="typeH" onchange="filterHeight(this)">
```

Where `this` refers to the `select` element itself, so you can access its value inside the callback function.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo snippet:

```js
function filterHeight(select) {
  if (select.value !== "feet") {
    document.getElementById("height2").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("height2").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action=" " onsubmit="">Enter your Height:
  <input type="text" id="height"> </input>
  Feet <input type="text" id="height2"> </input>Inches
  <select id="typeH" onchange="filterHeight(this)">
    <option value="feet">Feet/àInches</option>
    <option value="cm">Centimeter</option>
  </select>
```