# Show/hide select options based on value of another select using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I want to select and get results but options should be invisible so when I select name they show up like that

```html
# SELECT FROM 
<select>
    <option value="n">name/option>
    <option value="a">age</option>
    <option value="c">country</option>
</select>  
# GET 
<select>
    <!-- # IF YOU SELECT NAME THESE SHOW UP -->
    <option value="1">john</option>
    <option value="2">dan</option>
</select>
<select>
    <!-- IF YOU SELECT AGE THESE SHOW UP -->
    <option value="1">23</option>
    <option value="2">24</option>
</select>
<select>
    <!-- IF YOU SELECT COUNTRY THESE SHOW UP -->
    <option value="1">uk</option>
    <option value="2">usa</option>
</select>
```

but select tag should not be invisible. coz the HTML page cant be blank I want to make options only to  be invisible

Comment: Hi, can you post some tries? so we can help you to fix them.

Comment: You'll need JS to get the selected option and then enable the next options.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide elements based on a selected option with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832785/show-hide-elements-based-on-a-selected-option-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

When main `<select>` is changed, get value of selected option and using it, select relevant select tag and show it.

```js
$(".main").change(function(){
  $("."+$(this).val()).show().siblings().not(".main").hide()
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
# SELECT FROM 
<select class="main">
  <option value="n">name</option>
  <option value="a">age</option>
  <option value="c">country</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="n">
  # IF YOU SELECT NAME THESE SHOW UP
  <option value="1">john</option>
  <option value="2">dan</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="a">
  # IF YOU SELECT AGE THESE SHOW UP
  <option value="1">23</option>
  <option value="2">24</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="c">
  IF YOU SELECT COUNTRY THESE SHOW UP
  <option value="1">uk</option>
  <option value="2">usa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: u made my day @Mohammad i spent alot time testing the codes which works for me. but finally finished and urs worked coz no need to hide and most codes was needing hidden but urs worked nice with class only

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category1 :</td>
        <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
          <select name="category1" id="category1">
            <option value="">Select Category1</option>
            <option value="n">name</option>
            <option value="a">age</option>
            <option value="c">country</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">Category2 :</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
          <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
            <option value>Select Category2</option>
            <!-- Home Ware -->
            <optgroup data-rel="n">
              <option value="1">john</option>
              <option value="2">dan</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Education -->
            <optgroup data-rel="a">
              <option value="1">23</option>
              <option value="2">24</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Books -->
            <optgroup data-rel="c">
              <option value="1">uk</option>
              <option value="2">usa</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    var $cat = $("#category1"),
        $subcat = $(".subcat");

    var optgroups = {};

    $subcat.each(function(i,v){
        var $e = $(v);
        var _id = $e.attr("id");
            optgroups[_id] = {};
            $e.find("optgroup").each(function(){
        var _r = $(this).data("rel");
        $(this).find("option").addClass("is-dyn");
        optgroups[_id][_r] = $(this).html();
            });
    });
    $subcat.find("optgroup").remove();

    var _lastRel;
    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        if(_lastRel === _rel) return true;
        _lastRel = _rel;
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        $subcat.find(".is-dyn").remove();
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.each(function(){
            var $el = $(this);
          var _id = $el.attr("id");
          $el.append(optgroups[_id][_rel]);
        });
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});
```

DEMO:

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/1762/)

Answer (score 0):

Just give your select tags the appropriate ids and hide/show them in the change event of the first select.

You can hide the selects in your html by using the hidden attribute.

```js
$('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
    $('select:not(#dropdown)').hide(); //hides all selects except the one with id "dropdown"
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show(); //shows the select where id = #dropdown's value ("n"/"a"/"c")
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="n">name</option>
    <option value="a">age</option>
    <option value="c">country</option>
</select>


<select id="n">
    <option value="1">john</option>
    <option value="2">dan</option>
</select>

<select id="a" hidden>
    <option value="1">23</option>
    <option value="2">24</option>
</select>


<select id="c" hidden>
    <option value="1">uk</option>
    <option value="2">usa</option>
</select>
```